# Google Maps working correctly in browser but not in Android app

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I have a phonegap application in which i'm trying to integrate Google maps to show.

I'm toggling through the visibilty of divs with the following script (i also added here the map script so it would initialize when the div is shown) :

```
function showMe( elem ) {
      $$( '.toggle' ).each( function( toggle ) {
        if ( toggle.id == $(elem).id ){
          toggle.show();
          if ( toggle.id == $(contact).id ) {
                    jQuery('#contact').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    var minZoomLevel = 14;

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                        zoom: minZoomLevel,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.444512, 26.09725),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });
                }                           
          else   jQuery('#contact').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }
        else
          toggle.hide();

      });
    }
```

I have four divs with the coresponding id and a footer from where i toggle the display of the divs with :

```
onclick="showMe('div ID');"
```

On the 'contact' div where i'm trying to show the map i have the following

```
<div data-role="content" class="toggle" rel="external" id="contact" style="display:block; visibility:hidden;">
            <div class="content_holder">                    
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:380px; width:auto; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i load it in my browser it works corectly but On my mobile device it only shows a grey spot in the div where the map should load.

In my config.xml i have added:

```
<access origin="http://google.com/" />
```

and in index.html i'm using the following script source which is for maps api v3 :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem, it happens when a Google Map is **drawed** into an element without width and height or into an element that is set to display: none the problem then occurs when you toggle it to display: block or give it width and height

So your options may be

To rewrite your toggle hide each iteration to somethings that toggles the visibilty-state

And it would work, but it might break up your layout, so your better option I guess is to initiate the Google Map not on document ready but on the moment when you toggle the map-container-element to show()

In any way, at the moment you initiate the Google Map, the wrapping element my not be set to display: none

Comment: i'm not quite sure i understand. "visibility" doesnt have the "none" property. And where should i put it? When my page loads i want it to show only the "index" div. If i remove display:none from the "contact" div the map will load corectly but on the first page under the "index" div which i dont want

Comment: i edited the showMe function and i toggle the visibility and i only added display:block and visibility:hidden to the #content div and now it works on the web browser :D But I build it with phonegap but it didnt show on my first try. i have <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
in head and  <access origin="http://google.com/" /> in confi.xml . Do i need to add something else? or change the script source?

Comment: run your "new google.maps.map()" function when you show the wrapping element then it will work on phone gap too

Comment: i edited the show me script like you sugested but in still won't load in Android app. You can see the edits in my question. Please do you have any ideea why it still won't work?